# Invoke a protractor test using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, protractor, automated-tests

**TL;DR: I have a few protractor tests that I want to invoke using python.

The main idea is to run a script in python, that will invoke the test, and return me the result(whether the test succeed or failed, including errors).**

Each protractor test I'm running is exporting a jasmine-reporter, so basically, I wish to read from the XML file the results and just print them.

The main issue I'm having is to invoke the test itself.
I was thinking maybe to invoke a new terminal(I'm using Mac), and execute a simple command of 'protractor '.

I found a script (terminal.py) that allows to open a new terminal window and execute some commands within it ([Git](https://github.com/skywind3000/terminal)).
Trying to use it came out like:

```
from terminal import *

terminal_instance = Terminal
Terminal.run_command(self=terminal_instance, command="protractor ~/Git/webapp/test/'new test'/login/protractor.conf.js",
                     profile="profile", title="run a protractor test", wait=0, terminal="terminal", cwd=None)
```

The relevant functions within the module are:

```
def execute (self, terminal, title, script, cwd, wait, profile):
    lines = [ line for line in script ]
    windows = self.check_windows(terminal)
    script = []
    if cwd == None:
        cwd = os.getcwd()
    if terminal == None:
        terminal = ''
    if sys.platform[:3] == 'win' and cwd[1:2] == ':':
        if terminal in ('', 'system', 'dos', 'win', 'windows', 'command', 'cmd'):
            script.append(cwd[:2])
            script.append('cd "%s"'%cwd)
        else:
            script.append('cd "%s"'%self.config.win2cyg(cwd))
    elif sys.platform == 'cygwin':
        if terminal in ('dos', 'win', 'cmd', 'command', 'system', 'windows'):
            path = self.config.cyg2win(os.path.abspath(cwd))
            script.append(path[:2])
            script.append('cd "%s"'%path)
        else:
            script.append('cd "%s"'%cwd)
    else:
        script.append('cd "%s"'%cwd)
    script.extend(lines)
    if wait:
        if windows:
            script.append('pause')
        else:
            script.append('read -n1 -rsp "press any key to confinue ..."')
    if self.post_command:
        script.append(self.post_command)
    return self.open_terminal(terminal, title, script, profile)

def run_command (self, terminal, title, command, cwd, wait, profile):
    script = [ command ]
    return self.execute(terminal, title, script, cwd, wait, profile)
```

Running this python file gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/yoavserrouya/Git/webapp/test/new test/python/Integrate py-pro.py", line 5, in 
>       profile="profile", title="run a protractor test", wait=0, terminal="terminal", cwd=None)
>     File "/Users/yoavserrouya/Git/webapp/test/new test/python/terminal.py", line 631, in run_command
>       return self.execute(terminal, title, script, cwd, wait, profile)
>   TypeError: execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'profile'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Does anyone knows how I can deal with it?
Or, alternatively has another idea on how I can execute the protractor tests using a python script?

Comment: Am I missing something, or isn't it as simple as `import os
os.system("./protractor conf")` ?

Comment: It is one of the options, but for some unknown reason, when I run it with the mentioned script, the XML output(jasmine report) file is not created. On the other hand, running the protractor test directly from the terminal does create this output for me.

Comment: Is the XML being returned in `stdout` ?

Comment: Apparently the output file was created, with a different path though so I just missed it.
The solution of os.system actually works pretty well. Thanks!